# Segmentation Fault on fopen

Tags: c

I'm getting an odd segmentation fault on the first line of my code.

All I do is call

```
FILE *src = fopen(argv[1], 'r');
```

And I get a seg fault with the message in gdb...

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

```
0x00007ffff779956d in _IO_file_fopen () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

I copy the name of the file directly into the run-time execution. Thoughts?

Comment: And you _do_ pass an argument to your program?

Comment: Your compiler should have given a warning that your arguments were wrong.

Answer (score 14):

The second argument to [`fopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) should be a string, not a `char`:

```
FILE *src = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

Note the double quotes.

It is always a good idea to switch on compiler warnings and to keep an eye on them. My compiler picks up on the incorrect argument:

```
test.c:4:1: warning: passing argument 2 of 'fopen' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from test.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:250:7: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'int'
```

Comment: @Avidanborisov: it was implicitly converted to a pointer if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @someguy But implicit conversion between integers and pointers doesn't exist (except for 0).

Comment: @Avidanborisov: The specification says otherwise. See section 6.3.2.3: "An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified [when the value is 0], the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation."

Comment: The link @NPE gave says: "Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be specified by means of an **explicit cast**". So even if it may be converted, it still has to be done explicitly.

Comment: @Avidanborisov But a compiler is not required to produce an error on all code that violates the standard in any way, so it is okay if the code compiles. A compiler is required to emit a diagnostic for such constructs, though. Both gcc and clang do that by default.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the string passed is not null terminated, or you're acessing an invalid índex on argv

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
FILE *src = fopen(argv[1], 'r');
```

you need to write

```
FILE *src = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```